# SQL - calculate percentile based on customer spend

Tags: sql, percentile

I have to calculate top 33% customers, middle 33% customers and low 33% customers based on the customer spend. I have customer ID and their spend columns and I need to add new columns as top spenders, middle spenders, and low spenders after calculating who are top 33% customers and so on.

any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to do the calculating using `rank()` or `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when rank() over (order by spend) <= 0.33 * count(*) over ()
             then 'low'
             when when rank() over (order by spend) <= 0.67 * count(*) over ()
             then 'medium'
             else 'high'
        end) as spend_group
from t;
```

You can also use the `ntile()` window function.  I prefer to do the calculation more explicitly in order to have more control over what happens in the event of ties.  Using `rank()` all customers with the same spend are in the same group.

Comment: The count is so huge is that percentile all  under 0.17. There is no way I'm able to get top 33, top 67 etc. What you do when you have huge count?

Comment: @Rupz . . . That would only happen if almost all your values of `spend` were the same.  If this is the case, then I would suggest that you ask another question.